# Ruby's return values

Tags: ruby

I'm confused about the returning values in Ruby. For example, if I do

```
(1..5).each {|i| puts 2*i}
```

it returns

```
=> 1..5
```

I just don't know why it happens. It seems sometimes it returns more than one variable?

Comment: Why would you use the return value from that code, anyways?

Comment: `1..5` is a single range object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything in ruby is an expression.* Expression has a value. `each` evaluates to the object it iterated. In this case it's a `Range` object.

Take a look at [definition of Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each):

```
               VALUE
rb_ary_each(VALUE array)
{
    long i;
    volatile VALUE ary = array;

    RETURN_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0);
    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        rb_yield(RARRAY_PTR(ary)[i]);
    }
    return ary;
}
```

For every element in the input array it calls the block, and then returns the input array.

* *From the top of my head, I can't name a thing in ruby that's not an expression.*

Comment: shouldn't it return the last expression? So it should be the last number calculated, but why it returns the whole range instead?

Comment: @user1229490 - `each` is a looping structure. It's meant to do operations inside the loop, not to return values. If you want to return something from inside the loop then you use `map` or some other sort of operation.